# Get min date of the closest left datepicker

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have several datepickers :

```
$('.datepicker_debut_s_c').datepicker(
        {
            dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
            changeYear: true,
            maxDate: null
        });     

        $('.datepicker_fin_s_c').datepicker(
        {
            dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
            changeYear: true,
            maxDate: null,
            minDate: $(".datepicker_debut_s_c").datepicker("getDate")
        });
```

I would like to get the min date from the left datepicker (see image below) to have a coherence in my dates.

The problem is that the min date is always the date choosen in the first datepicker and not from the precedent...

[image: like you can see, I choose 2014/120/02 but the min date is 2014/12/28 (the date picker left above)]

This is my html code (just a part) :

```
<table id="dates_stages_comp">
      <tbody><tr>
       <th>Nom</th><th>Prénom</th><th>Matricule</th><th>Année</th><th>Dates début</th><th>Date fin</th><th>Type de stage</th><th>Nombre de jours prestés</th><th>Nombre de jours à prester</th><th>Différence</th><th>&nbsp;</th>
      </tr><tr><td>Dupont</td><td>Lajoie</td><td>313278</td><td>PHAR5S-D</td><td><input id="date_debut_stage_comp#313278" class="datepicker_debut_s_c hasDatepicker" value="28-12-2014" type="text"></td><td><input id="date_fin_stage_comp#313278" class="datepicker_fin_s_c hasDatepicker" value="30-06-2015" type="text"></td><td>
                      <select id="sel_type_stage_comp#313278">
                        <option value="0">Type du stage</option>
                        <option value="1">Stage complémentaire</option>
                        <option value="2">Stage ERASMUS</option>
                        <option value="3" selected="selected">Stage recherche</option>
                      </select>
                      </td><td>184</td><td>180</td><td><span class="vert"> +4 </span></td></tr>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You usually use the onSelect method for the jQuery UI datepicker, to get the selected date, so with multiple datepickers, I assume you would have 2 different onSelect methods

```
$("#datePicker1").datepicker({
    onSelect: function(selectedDate) {
        console.log(selectedDate);
    }
});

$("#datePicker2").datepicker({
    onSelect: function(selectedDate) {
        console.log(selectedDate);
    }
});
```

[demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/StevenIseki/t0xd67ec/)